# How to preserve collection view scroll position after changing ViewController in SWIFT

Tags: swift, collectionview

The problem is: after scrolling the collectionView and clicking on an item another viewController is presented via navigationController. When I tap on the 'Back' button (top-left) the collection view scrolls to top, but I want it to keep the "scroll position" that it had before changing view controller.

I tried adding
automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has nothing to do with what you are dealing with.
The collectionView should not scroll back to top by itself. You are probably calling `reloadData()` in `viewDidAppear` or `viewWillAppear` which triggers the behavior you are describing.

Comment: I'm not reloading it, but you are right. The collection view is being recreated every time in the viewWillAppear